# How to disable "non-interactive elements with click handlers must have at least one keyboard listener" rule in eslint?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Whenever I write an `onClick` event attribute without an `onKeyUp` for example, the error is raised by eslint

> Visible, non-interactive elements with click handlers must have at
> least one keyboard listener

I can't figure out how to disable this rule. How do I do this?

Comment: This eslint error exists for a reason and you probably shouldn't disable it. Ignoring it means that visually impaired people will not be able to use your website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 'off'` in your eslint config should disable it.

Comment: @Joseph the reason why people down vote the answer is not because it is not working. people also down vote the answer when the answer works but works as an workaround, not an absolute solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do not disable this eslint rule. It exists to help you make sure that your site is accessible to people who are using screen readers.

You can easily write code that complies with this rule by doing something like the following:

```
<someElement onClick={this.handleClick} onKeyDown={this.handleClick}>
```

Alternatively, you can use a prebuilt component from a library, like https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/ , which will comply with accessibility standards by default and save you some work.

Comment: I started using UI libraries for my website, so it contains accessible components. Sometimes I switch off rules to continue development and fix code that ignores rules later.

Comment: unfortunately, some of us with corporate jobs can't just switch out style frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable it as

#### Solution 1:

```
<someElement onClick={this.handleClick} onKeyDown={this.handleClick}  aria-hidden="true" >
```

#### Pros:

- You don't have to disable to it for project as in disabling rule in config etc

#### Cons:

- visually impaired people will not be detect this `someElement`, as using `aria-hidden="true"` would remove it from accessibility tree. hence won't be able interact.

That's why, I mostly go with other solution in such case.

#### Solution 2:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events
<someElement onClick={this.handleClick}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under `rules` in .eslintrc.js

```
vuejs-accessibility/click-events-have-key-events': 'off',
```